# How do I correct this Swift enum?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

In the PluralSight course "Swift First Look" there is a section on Enums which appears to be out of date. The code provided is this:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

enum CardType: String {
    case AmericanExpress = "AmericanExpress"
    case Visa = "Visa"
    case Discover = "Discover"
    case MasterCard = "MasterCard"
    case None = "None"

    private func regularExpression() -> NSRegularExpression {
        switch self {
        case .Visa:
            return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$", options: nil, error: nil)
        case .AmericanExpress:
            return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^4[47][0-9]{13}$", options: nil, error: nil)
        case .MasterCard:
            return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$", options: nil, error: nil)
        case .Discover:
            return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$", options:nil, error:nil)
        default:
            return NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*", options:nil, error:nil)
        }
    }

    func isValidFor(cardNumber: String) -> Bool {
        let re = self.regularExpression()
        let range = NSRange(0..<cardNumber.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
        let matches = re.numberOfMatches(in: cardNumber, options: .anchored, range: range)
        return matches > 0
    }

    static let allValues = [Visa, AmericanExpress, Discover, MasterCard]

    static func from(cardNumber: String) -> CardType? {
        for type in self.allValues {
            if type.isValidFor(cardNumber: cardNumber) {
                return type
            }
        }
    }
}

CardType.Visa.isValidFor(cardNumber: "4242424242424242")
CardType.Visa.isValidFor(cardNumber: "1234")

CardType.from(cardNumber: "4242424242424242").rawValue
```

The problem with this is that the return statements in the switch block all have this error reported by the latest version of XCode:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Also, the last line reports this error:

```
Value of optional type 'CardType?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

How do I correct this and what is the current version of Swift requiring here?

Note: Yes, I'm just starting with Swift.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Or what version of Xcode. The code you have shown is written for Swift 1.x, as the Swift language is changing so swift, it's too, too, too old to learn with. The latest version of Swift is 3.0 comes with Xcode 8. If you cannot find a more up-to-date course, you need to face similar issues for a huge amount of times.

Comment: I'm using the latest XCode Swift but the course is from 2014. I just need to know what changes to make.

Comment: Generally, "do everything for me" questions are not welcome here. The code is written for Swift 1.x, you say you are using the latest Xcode, which means you are using Swift 3. With showing what you have done till now, you would get better and quicker responses.

Comment: I don't need the whole of Swift explained, just the corrections to those lines. Yes, it's in Swift 1.x, but that's because the tutorial I have right now is a bit out of date. This is what I've done till now - I'm literally on day 1. I haven't written any other Swift.

Comment: Find Xcode 6.4 containing Swift 1.2, your code would work on it with very few fixes. And then get Xcode 7.0 which helps you to migrate your code to Swift 2.0, then get Xcode 7.3.1 which migrate the code to Swift 2.2. And then open the project in your Xcode 8.

Comment: Just a side note. You can remove the `= "Visa"` etc... When setting the associated type to String the rawValue becomes a String of the name of the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSRegularExpression()` initializer has changed.  You have to pass `[]` instead of `nil` for options (but since that is the default value, you can leave off `options` altogether), and you have to deal with the fact that it can throw an error.  Since you are dealing with static patterns that won't fail, you can call them with `try!`.  In general, that is dangerous because it will crash if an error is returned.  With these static patterns, that won't happen (or you'll fix it when it does).

Change:

```
return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$", options: nil, error: nil)
```

to:

```
return try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$")
```

and repeat that for all of the `NSRegularExpressions`.

For the last line, you just need a `?`:

```
CardType.from(cardNumber: "4242424242424242")?.rawValue
```

Finally, this function needs a `return nil` to account for the case when a `CardType` is not found in the `for` loop:

```
static func from(cardNumber: String) -> CardType? {
    for type in self.allValues {
        if type.isValidFor(cardNumber: cardNumber) {
            return type
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that is helpful! Just what I needed. These errors do take a bit of getting used to but at least these make sense now.

Comment: You're welcome.  A lot has changed since Swift 1.1.  The Swift 2.2 -> 3.0 transition is another huge one for the APIs.  Autocomplete is your friend.  For these APIs that have changed (and nearly everything has), try typing them from scratch and see what Autocomplete suggests.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'm using autocomplete as much as I can, but it's the errors which are alien. Coding on Mac is new to me, though coding isn't. Btw, when I put return .None instead of return nil I get the error 'None' has been renamed to 'none', but putting a different CardType return value is fine. I can explicitly put CardType.None though.

Comment: The .None thing is interesting. There are two .Nones at play here. The underlying implementation of Optional types is an enum with two cases .Some and .None. If an optional is nil, it has the value .None. If it had a value, then it is .Some and the value is stored as the associated value of the enum. In Swift 3, these were renamed to .some and .none with lowercase letters. So Swift thinks .None refers to the optional .none because from is returning an optional CardType.

Comment: I believe that the None case for CardType is not needed. This is handled by the fact that from returns an optional CardType? Which expresses that no CardType could be assigned.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! I thought it was something like that but couldn't place it exactly. Awesome :)